# If I have buttons within my app that connect to links would that be copyright infringement?

Tags: android, ios

I am making an app that has links to funny things across the internet,would that be considered copyright infringement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [licensing advice is off-topic on Stack Overflow.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) You may be able to get help on [Programmers Stack Exchange, but **read their faq carefully** before proceeding.](//meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/when-is-a-software-licensing-question-on-topic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links to sites would not be considered copyright infringement. For more information, check out this helpful link: http://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/website-permissions/linking/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your country and also if the webpage on which you provide the link has Policy restricting it.

But generally no, copyright mainly resides on the content of the web page per se. (Is like sharing a web page on social media)

Also in no way yo can claim to be the creator of that page.